# Just wondering if the SE team has seen this 3rd party spam blocking service

Tags: discussion, spam-detection

I stumbled upon this: http://www.stopforumspam.com/ just now and wondered if it has been considered (or is even known about) for the StackExchange signup procedure?  Maybe not necessarily to block people from signing up (false positives?) but maybe to make more verification needed, or flag the user as a probable spammer?

Comment: It has "forum" in its URL. You do know we're not a forum, right? ;-)

Comment: That may be so, but we still suffer from the same kind of things as a forum in the same way.  Spammers sign up and then post spam.  Just like in a forum.  Anything we can do to stop them signing up in the first place has to be good, yes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would be wise to lean on an external partner. There is an API limit for reqeusts (I don't know the subsciption rate for SE, but again, leaning on an external partner that has obvious limits might be tricky).

Though a good initiative it may be, I'm not fully convinced the site you link to is a good solution for a community as large as this. I must say that the site itself is not a real big insentive to 'believe' in the product. Do you have personal experience with the product/site/API ?

Comment: Not yet - I have only recently found it.  It is quite well liked by the Drupal community, with a well used Drupal module supporting it (spambot).  I am trying it out on one of my sites that doesn't get many hits, and what it does get is usually from spammers.